# How to replace skin color variant emojis in string?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, emoji

How can emoji variants be replaced with another character?

For example,  should result in `xxxxxx` where `x` is the replacement character. Note that each emoji should be replaced with one `x`.

What doesn't work:

```js
const regex = new RegExp('[]', 'igu');
const s = '';
const m = s.match(regex); // ["","","","","","","","",""]
const r = s.replace(regex, 'x'); // xxxxxxxxx
```

The above has 9 matches, apparently matching / replacing some surrogates separately.

Why is that?

Comment: Do you want to specifically replace these 6 emojis? Or any emojis?

Comment: These emojis are just an example. It should be specific emojis with a skin tone or gender variant, but I don't want to just replace *every* emoji in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the emojis by length in descending order, then build the regex dynamically with `RegExp` constructor:

```js
const arr = ['','','','','',''];
arr.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
const regex = new RegExp(arr.join('|'), 'g');
const s = '';
const m = s.match(regex);
console.log(m); // => ["", "", "", "", "", ""]
const r = s.replace(regex, 'x');
console.log(r); // => xxxxxx
```

Comment: So that the longest unicode sequence is matched first and no surrogate characters remain, is that why this works?

Comment: @Manuel Yes, it is  a universal NFA (so called regex directed regex engines) regex "trick", the longer alternatives must be put first in the alternation, as the first alternative "wins" and the rest is not even tried.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, it makes total sense and is a clever trick if one just wants to specify the emojis to match without having to worry about base and surrogate characters, ie. how these emojis are actually constructed.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the question here is explicitly how to replace *specific* emojis, not any emoji. I still think your answer is great because the composition of emojis can get quite complex if there are multiple modifiers. In complex cases, instead of deconstructing emojis and creates a regex for it, this may be the easier way. The downside may be that each emoji has to be listed explicitly, which can make the regex longer, and maybe less readable.

Answer (score 1):

Emojis are complicated, each basic symbol ("presentation") can be followed by a sequence of "modifiers", which provide additional styling for a symbol. See [UTS 51](http://unicode.org/reports/tr51/) if you want to know all the details (you don't).

In this particular case, you have to match/replace a presentation symbol, followed by some modifier symbols to make it work as inteded:

```js
const s = '';

const regex = /\p{Emoji_Presentation}\p{Emoji_Modifier}*/gu;

const m = s.match(regex);
console.log(...m, m.length) // 6

const r = s.replace(regex, 'x'); 
console.log(r, r.length) // 6
```

Comment: I'll accept your answer because it contains references and mentions the unicode property escapes; I'll mention my answer as well, since it shows how to even match specific skin tones.

Comment: @Manuel Then [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68137190/how-to-replace-skin-color-variant-emojis-in-string/68137268?noredirect=1#comment120427108_68137190) is wrong. This will affect all emojis.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are actually right. This does not distinguish based on specific emojis. I think my own answer, similar to this answer would be the most specific one.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this approach to define the base characters and add optional modifiers:

```
const regex = new RegExp('[]?', 'gu');

const s = '';
const m = s.match(regex);
const r = s.replace(regex, 'x');
```

This is similar to [georg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68137268/1870795). The advantage here is that it allows to specify the specific skin tones to match, so the regex can be more granular.